# How do you import in Genie?

Tags: import, include, vala, genie

How is one supposed to import modules or libraries in the Genie programming language?  I looked through the documentation and examples, but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

The method is the same as in Vala:

[View documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Vala/SharedLibSample)

The example can be used with this code:

```
//--- libreria.gs ---
namespace mate
    def sum(a:int,b:int):int
        return a+b
```

and you can compile with:
**valac --library=libreria -H libreria.h libreria.gs -X -fPIC -X -shared -o libreria.so**
this command creates ".vapi",".h" and ".so" extent files.

I hope this will be helpfull.:>